# SQL query to get the next step of process if the previous step has 'COMPLETED' using group by clause and joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, having

I did a lot of effort to retrieve the desired output from tables. But unfortunately, it didn't work out. I have 3 tables *process*, *process_steps*, and *steps*:

[image]

Problem Statment: **I want to fetch the "next step" for all the processes.**

**Output should be like this** :

| id | process_id | next_step | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Complete Form | active |
| 2 | 2 | Send the document | active |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct on (ps.process_id) p.*,s.name as next_step
FROM public.process_steps ps 
JOIN public.steps s on ps.step_id = s.id
JOIN public.process p on p.id = ps.process_id
WHERE ps.status != 'COMPLETED'
ORDER BY ps.process_id desc, ps.step_id ASC;
```

I heve tested this query, it is fetching all next step of processes. I hope it would be helpful.